# NAT Possible with Zero Configuration Networking

Tags: gateway, upnp, zeroconf, miniupnpc

Is it possible in windows which has static ip set in his system can take ip from 169.254.0.0/16 pool and set its gateway as 169.254.1.1 automatically from linux server.

So that each request can be NAT if required .
I thought GRP(Gateway response protocol) is the answer but that's not it, no practical implementation is present for linux and windows APIPA does not take gateway.